# How do I load jquery library and a js file into wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying for the past day to load the jquery library and a js file into my WordPress theme but have no idea how to do this and everywhere I look the instructions are different and haven't worked.

Currently:

functions.php

```
<?php

function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

function enqueue_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

function enqeue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('homeSlider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/homeSlider.js', array('jquery'));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheets');
```

header.php

```
<head> 

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  

    <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>

    <meta name="description" content="<?php get_bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>">

   <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add the scripts what you want in the `enqeue_scripts` function. You only need duplicate the current function and update it with the information that you need. PD: jQuery is already loaded.

```
function enqeue_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('homeSlider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/homeSlider.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('a unique name', 'source_path/js/another.js');
}
```

This is the [function documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

The `wp_enqueue_script` function need at least 2 parameters: a unique name (as string) and the path to the script. You can use the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` function to get the full path to the root theme directory and then concatenate the rest of path to the js file.

The third parameter is an array of dependencies scripts. Example: the current script in the code, named "homeSlide" has as dependency to jQuery. If your script depends on jQuery, you need to specify it.

And, you need to hook this functions properly.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqeue_scripts' );
```

Your entire code should be like this:

```
<?php

function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

function enqueue_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

function enqeue_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('homeSlider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/homeSlider.js', array('jquery'));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheets');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqeue_scripts');
```

Comment: As you can see from my original post, I've already done this. It still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to fix the name of the action function that you are calling. See: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqeue_scripts' );

Comment: This creates an error message "
Warning
: Missing argument 2 for add_action(), called in /homepages/19/d635628066/htdocs/ArmstrongWebsiteTest/wp-content/themes/Armstrong/functions.php on line 13 and defined in 
/homepages/19/d635628066/htdocs/ArmstrongWebsiteTest/wp-includes/plugin.php
on line 
398". And it still doesn't make jquery work.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you see if you paste properly both arguments of the `add_action` function?  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqeue_scripts' );

Comment: Yes. If I put it the way you showed it comes up with the error message. Seems to be that it doesn't like the 'enqeue_scripts' part but has no problem with 'wp_enqeue_scripts'

Comment: Can you update the code of your question with your current code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135087/discussion-between-kevin-jimenez-and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

It's not compulsory to add css & js files through functions.php file, you can directly add css & js files in header.php

Just like this:

```
<head> 

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  

    <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>

    <meta name="description" content="<?php get_bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>">

    //Include CSS files
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/css/style.css">

    //Including JS files
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/homeSlider.js"></script>

   <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

I hope, this may help you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This works, but it's the incorrect way!!

Comment: May be, but when we create custom themes, we directly add these css & js in header files & for those js files which runs in the footer are included in the footer.php before wp_footer() function.

Comment: have you given the right path & right js & css? And please comment the above wp_enqueue_script function in which you have enqueued the required js & css.

Comment: Is there any cache plugin? How the site is not reading the css & js when included directly in the header? I am also confused.